# Django - Form template throws "This field is required" for Imagefield

Tags: django

I'm having some trouble with image upload in Django 3.0. I'm experiencing the issue where trying to upload an image from my template throws the error "This field is required" even though i have a file selected. It uploads fine I do it from the form in the admin area.

models.py

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```py
def new_post_view(request):
    new_img = ImageForm(request.POST or None)

    if new_img.is_valid():
        new_img.save()
        new_img = ImageForm()
        return redirect('imageposts:gallery')
    return render(request, 'imageposts/create.html', {'new_pic': new_img})
```

forms.py

```py
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = [
            "title",
            "image",
        ]

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(),
            "image": forms.FileInput(),
        }
```

create.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{new_pic.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Add image</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Solutions i've seen have been to make the field nullable and empty, but for this case, the image is an always required, but it's just not uploading the selected file. The form just clears the file section and throws "This field is required." I've tried in both django 3.0 and django 2.2 and I get the same result. I can't tell what it is I'm doing wrong here, and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: if image is not required, use "null=True, blank=True" in model in ImageField and migrate

Comment: You haven't passed `request.FILES` to the form. See the docs on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole logic is wrong here.Change your view like this

```
def new_post_view(request):
    img_form = ImageForm()
    #now check if the request is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # you need request.files also since the Image is the Filefield
       img_form = ImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES) 
       if img_form.is_valid():
           img_form.save()
           return redirect('imageposts:gallery')
    return render(request, 'imageposts/create.html', {'form': img_form})
```

Now in the template instead of `{{new_pic.as_p}}` do `{{form.as_p}}`